# Is commands order important?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1

I'm trying to copy a directory *(contains some folders and files)* by windows Commmand line. Based on some searches, I've found two commands:

This:

```
xcopy /E c:\source c:\dest
```

And this:

```
xcopy c:\source c:\dest /s /e /h
```

---

Two question:

1. Is there any difference between `/e` and `\E`? I mean is being capital important?
2. Is there any difference between different orders? Like these?

   - `xcopy /E c:\source c:\dest`
   - `xcopy c:\source c:\dest /E`

Comment: Your question number one contains an error. You never used `\E` and as for parameter passing it would be wildly different from a slash. A switch with a backslash would probably be used as a argument rather than a switch. As for the order it would also depend on the command. You would have to look at the help of the command (`xcopy /?`) and try to use that pattern to be safe.

Comment: @Seth Ah .. thx for the tip ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In case of `xcopy`

In case of `xcopy`, `/e` is no different from `/E` and you can place it almost anywhere.

### In case of other commands

Other command may not offer you this degree of flexibility. For example in `nbtstat`, `-r` is different from `-R`. Or in case of `ffmpeg`, it makes a lot of difference whether you put `-ss` before `-i` or after it.

Comment: Thx buddy `:-)` .. ! Upvote

Comment: And one question else: Do you know how can I make a folder *(directory)* in windows 8.1 command line? I want to make one to copy everything in it.

Comment: `md "foldername"`. Replace `foldername` with the name you want.

Comment: Thx again pal `:-)`

Comment: and my last question: I'm reading the meaning of [parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx) and honestly I'm confused ..! Which parameter do I need exactly? `:-(` I just want to copy **everything** *(folders, files, sub folders, hidden ones, empty ones etc ..)* ..! Do you know what parameter do I need?

Comment: You need `/herk`. Or if you prefer, `/h /e /r /k`. Both do the same thing.